# How to fix "Running out of memory" issue while running power queries in 32 bit ms office 2013

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a Excel workbook developed in 64 bit ms excel 2016(windows). it has 44 queries/connection. Out of this 40 of them are connections.(there are 6 main tables users will update their values in that based on this we will do several data transformation mapping back-end tables) When i refresh the queries in my system no errors it works like a champ it hardly take 30 seconds to refresh all these, if someone else with 2013 32 bit ms office try to refresh they are getting "running out of memory" issues.

At the time of development stage stakeholder was not revealed that the users are using 32 bit 2013 ms office. During the testing we have realized this fact.

I have tried following options in Query Options

1. Enabled "Fast Data Load" in Global Query Options
2. Increased "Maximum allowed (MB) to 500" in Data Cache Management Options
3. Selected "Always ignore privacy level settings" in Global Privacy levels
4. Disabled "Create relationships between tables when adding to the Data Model for the first time" in current workbook Data load option
5. Disables "Allow data preview to download in the background" in current workbook Data load option

Comment: sorry, that's typo error. Actual value is 500

Comment: Add more RAM / upgrade to 64 bit...

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot do any one of these, approx 120 users are going to use this template and all of them are using SAP Analyzer Excel add-in that works only in 32 Bit MS Office

Comment: How much data are you actually running through Power Query? What kind of operations are you performing on the data? It is possible you are simply breaking the limits of what is possible within the 32-bit memory limit. It is also possible that your queries have been setup in a way that is using more memory than is necessary to achieve your end goal.